# Numba can not compile a simple function

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to compile a simple function that takes an python list and then split it according to a list of index. I am new to numba and the docs have not help me.

**Problem**
I cant successfully compile the function

**Code to compile**
The arr variable is a python list of floats or integers and idx is a numpy array or python list of integers, the result out should be a 2d python list of floats or integers according to arr input

```
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('trial')
# Uncomment the following line to print out the compilation steps
cc.verbose = True



@cc.export('split_numba', 'f8[:](f8[:], i4[:])')
def split_numba(arr, idx):
    out = []
    s = 0
    for n in range(len(idx)):
        e = idx[n]
        out.append(arr[s:e])
        s = e

    return out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

**Error**

```
No conversion from list(array(float64, 1d, A))<iv=None> to array(float64, 1d, A) for '$60return_value.1', defined at None

File "RUT_COMPILE.py", line 38:
def split_numba(arr, idx):
    <source elided>
        
    return out
    ^

During: typing of assignment at C:\Users\chelo\OneDrive\ALCANTARILLADO_PyQt5\00_MODULOS\RUT_COMPILE.py (38)

File "RUT_COMPILE.py", line 38:
def split_numba(arr, idx):
    <source elided>
        
    return out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output type of the function is not correct since `out` is a *list of arrays*. It should be `'List(f8[:])(f8[:], i4[:])'` instead of `'f8[:](f8[:], i4[:])'`.

Note that the specified input is *not* a Python list: `f8[:]` reference a Numpy array type with 64-bit float items. The `List` type provided by Numba is also not a pure-Python list (called "reflected list" in the Numba documentation). It is an alternative list type that is typed (so Numba needs to convert pure-Python lists to typed lists for input lists and the reverse operation for output lists). Reflected lists support heterogeneous typed items. Such operation introduce an overhead which can be big if the amount of computation is small (this is your case).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jérôme Richard, could you point where to read about numba types for me to use?, this error is due to the types used as you said. You could also not specify a return type al let numba infer it. Greetings, Chelo.

Comment: You can get the list of basic types [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/types.html). For Python-related advanced type, it is [there](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html?highlight=dict#typed-list). As for the return type, yes, you can. One way is not to provide any signature so Numba ill lazily compile the function when the function is run the first time with the target parameters. This can be an issue in hot loops though. Another solution is to use `(f8[:], i4[:])` but I am not sure this is documented yet (nor if this is really a feature)